# Line detection in sketches

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I am looking for a way to find strokes in hand-drawn sketches. My actual approach is to apply adaptive thresholding and findContours from OpenCV. The issue with this is that findContours gives me the right hand side and the left hand side, the upper und lower contour of one single stroke. Is there any way to just derive one contour representation out of a hand-drawn stroke?

Thanks in advance

Edited:

Here is the code and an image of what I have achieved so far:

First I applied adaptive Thresholding to the initial image:

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(image, image, new Size(5, 5), 3);
Mat thresholded = Mat.zeros(image.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
```

Then I applied findCountours on the thresholded image and additionally approxPolyDB on each contour.

```
Imgproc.findContours(thresholded, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, new Point(0,0));

List<MatOfPoint> refinedContours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
    MatOfPoint2f approx = new MatOfPoint2f();
    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(mop2mop2f(contours.get(i)), approx, 6, true);
}
```

Afterwards I splitter each contour at points where the angle is bigger than a fixed threshold. As a last step I deleted all contours that aren't longer than a given threshold.

[In the picture you can see the thresholded image as the final contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOdoI.jpg)

My aim is to avoid parallel contours in a way that there is only one contour for one stroke in the sketched image.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code and a sample image?

Answer (score 0):

A contour finder is used to find contours. That makes only sense if you are interested in contours of let's say a body of some thickness.
You are interested in lines. If you apply a contour finder on a thick line you end up with 2 lines instead of one which gives you even more data to deal with.

I suggest you try a thinning algorithm instead. Binarize your image using a suitable threshold, then apply a thinning/skeletonization algorithm.

You can use morphological closing to fill some small gaps befor thinning if desired.

Use pruning algorithms to clean up your skeleton.

Read this:
http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/thin.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented some kind of thinning and it works like a charm, but do you have any idea on how to retrieve a representation of the thinned lines like findCountours does for contour lines?

Comment: if you mean the point vector that findContours returns, simply use the lines pixels as coordinates. If you thinned your line properly it will have a thickness of 1 so its pretty straight forward. Of course there are countless mathematical ways to extract features of such structures if you mean that.